# Multiple dynamic onclick buttons triggering multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, unbind

I have several buttons that are generated dynamically.
To handle the click events on those buttons I've been using:

```
$(document).on('click', '.button-class', function() {
    // code here
});
```

The problem is, if the button is dynamically generated again. The click event seems to be bound to the document or something and so clicking that button again will fire the code inside twice. If the button is dynamically generated again it triggers thrice. That's the big issue here because my site is no refresh. So there is instances where content is generated again.

I could use

```
$(document).unbind('click').on('click', '.delete-order-btn', function() {
    //Code
});
```

Using the unbind, and applying unbind to all my dynamically generated buttons causes them to no longer trigger if they are generated more than once.

Comment: How about simply not binding the event handler more than once? *"The click event seems to be bound to the document"* That's correct, after all you are selecting the document via `$(document)`.

Comment: How can I select my buttons then? Because it is generated dynamically. $(".button-name").on("click", function(){}); wont work on dynamic content

Comment: @guradio: That doesn't make sense. Then no event handler would be executed.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You should absolutely use event delegation. But you should only execute `$(document).on('click', '.button-class', function() { ... })` *once*, not every time a button is created.

Comment: Say I have 2 buttons: btn-edit and btn-delete .  the first I handle by: $(document).on('click', '.btn-edit', function() { ... }) how then do I handle the second?

Comment: OK, each different type of button obviously needs its own event handler if they do different things, so you would execute `$(document).on('click', '.button-<whatever>', function() { ... })` for each class only *once* on page load.

Comment: I do have multiple buttons with the same class. Example: I have a table generated dynamically with multiple rows, at the end of each row I have two buttons. Edit and Delete buttons. The only way I can trigger the click event on those buttons is using $(document).on(.........  because the buttons are generated dynamically. However, if for example, this table is called again, the buttons will now trigger twice because they are binded again.

Comment: *"because they are binded again"* And I am saying that you should not bind the event handler again. You should move the code that binds the handler out of the table generation code, since the table generation code is called more than once but the handlers only have to be bound once. Does what I am saying make sense?

Comment: Sorry about the mis-communication. You're right. Thanks for your help Felix!

Comment: By _"generated dynamically"_, do you mean they are generated through Ajax?